# Is the eventown problem solution unique up to isomorphism

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a town with a set of residents $X$, where $|X| = n$ (suppose $n$ even for simplicity here). The residents like forming clubs, and we have clubs $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_m \subseteq X$. The *eventown problem* is interested in the maximum number of clubs $m$ that can be formed with these specific rules:

1. All clubs are distinct.
2. A club must have an even number of members. $\forall i, |C_i|$ is even.
3. Any pair of two clubs shares an even number of members: $\forall i \neq j, |C_i \cap C_j|$ is even.

It is easy to show that the largest number of clubs possible is $m=2^{n/2}$. An easy construction to attain this bound goes as follow : Take any partition of $X$ into sets of size 2, $B_1,\ldots,B_{n/2}$, and consider the family $\mathcal{F}=\{\bigcup_{i\in S}B_i \ :\ S\subseteq [n/2] \}$

For any partition, this matches the required bound, and all these possibilities are pairwise isomorphic.

> Is the solution unique up to isomorphism, or are there some other constructions?

Comment: To check, are you familiar / comfortable with the linear algebraic proof? If yes, can you reproduce your version of the proof?

Comment: :) I actually teach it during a tutorial ^^ . you work in the vector space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$. If F is a family of club, then $F\perp F$ and $F\subseteq F^\perp$.  $V=span(F)$ is totally isotropic and $dim(V)\leq n/2$

Comment: In order for equality to occur, we need $span(F) = F$ and so $F$ is a linear subspace of dimension $n/2$. Taking a basis $B_1, B_2, \cdots B_{n/2}$ we get exactly the families that you described.

Comment: @Random It's not quite as immediate. How do you know that there is a basis where all elements have exactly 2 non-zero coordinates?

Comment: @Random Just thought you'd like to know that the claim is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of eventown tells us that at equality, the set of clubs can be represented in $ \mathbb{F}_2^n$, as a linear subspace $F$ of dimension $n/2$ (and $ F = F^\perp$). We will use this context.

Here is a counterexample when $n = 8$.

Let the clubs be spanned by

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Check that

- every vector has 4 1's,
- the intersection of any 2 vectors has 2 1's
- Linear independence: Vectors 1, 2, 3 are the only ones with a 1 in the last / second last / third last column, so can't be involved in the equation. Hence these vectors are linearly independent.

However, there isn't a pairing that we can do with the first coordinate.

---

Here is a counterexample when $n = 7$ (so not quite what is asked).

Let the clubs be spanned by

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Check that

- every vector has 4 1's,
- the intersection of any 2 vectors has 2 1's
- Linear independence: Vectors 1 and 2 are the only ones with a 1 in the last / second last column, so can't be involved in the equation. Hence these vectors are linearly independent.

However, there isn't a pairing that we can do with the first coordinate.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yea, I just realized that my proof doesn't work (and pointed out the error).

Comment: I was actually writing this exact same counter-example I just found. Then you can use the fact that in eventown problem, every maximal solution (not extendable) is maximum (of size $2^{n/2}$). Therefore you can extend this 3 sets into a solution of size $2^{n/2}$. But these 3 clubs will never be found from a partition : They have general intersection of odd size, which can never happen with the partitions. And they can be used for any $n$, just add few $0$

Comment: I wrote down the details, but I'll be happy to validate your answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues I just added an explicit example for $n = 8$. I can't find a counterexample for $n=6$ as yet.

Comment: I'm not sure they exist. Trivially they don't for $n=4$ and $n=5$. When I was looking for a counterexample, I started with 6 and I had to move up to 7. I'll see if I can prove it.

Comment: I confirm, if you try to build an Eventown club-system, you must get a partition of the ground set with 2-sets. (small cases analysis)

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Oh good to know. Thanks for asking this question, it was a fun exercise for me. I can't believe I didn't push this through in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Just writing down some details from the counter-example found by Calvin Lin.

Note that in a maximum solution derived from a partition of $X$, for any 3 clubs $C_1,C_2,C_3$, we have $\vert C_1\cap C_2 \cap C_3 \vert$ is also even.

Let $C_1,C_2,C_3$ be the following clubs in $\mathbb{F_2}^n$ (where the $\dots$ are all $0$ )

$$\begin{cases} 
C_1 &= &( & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots &)\\
C_2 &= &( & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \dots &)\\
C_3 &= &( & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots &)\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Note that they form an Eventown, but their global intersection is odd, therefore the will never be from a partition of the ground set $X$.

Now, we use the fact that in Eventown, any maximal solution (not extendable) is maximum (of size $2^{n/2}$).

Therefore we will have a maximal solution not isomorphic to the partition solution.

Comment: How do you know that any any initial set of vectors can be extended to maximum size?

Comment: It's a rather standard result for eventown that every maximal solution is maximum. It comes from the fact that every maximal totally isotropic subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ has dimension $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$. I'll edit with the details